# Django Ajax: Multiple request to getting triggered for single ajax GET request

Tags: jquery, html, django, ajax, python-3.x

I have a weird issue when I'm making ajax get request from my template to my view. when I click on the history button, I could see in the log that ajax has sent the request to two different URL's.

console log:

```
[06/Nov/2019 21:22:38] "GET /NewHandBook/UserHistory?uname=pvivek 
HTTP/1.1" 200 4306
[06/Nov/2019 21:22:38] "GET /NewHandBook/Home? HTTP/1.1" 200 9980
```

The requests should go only to `/NewHandBook/UserHistory` but not sure why its hitting `/NewHandBook/Home`.

My ajax call:

```
<form id="UserHistory">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fas fa-history"></i> History
        </button>
    </form>
    $(document).on('submit', '#UserHistory', function (e) {
                    console.log("clicked history button");
                    console.log(getCookie("userName"));
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/NewHandBook/UserHistory',
                        data: {
                            'uname': getCookie("userName")
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("executed userHistory")
                            console.log(getCookie("userName"));
                        }
                    })
                })
```

Urls.py

```
url('UserHistory', views.history)
```

views.py

```
def history(request):
    uname=request.GET.get('uname')
    result = UserQueryHistory.objects.filter(User_name=uname)
    return render(request, 'History/DbHistory.html', {"result": result})
```

Comment: i thing other `[06/Nov/2019 21:22:38] "GET /NewHandBook/Home? HTTP/1.1" 200 9980`  GET request is sent form submit event of your form.

Comment: Thanks a lot...As you said the issue was with form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have form and button „type submit”, click on button will submit your form. You font have `event.preventDefault`. That’s why this button trigger two request.

There are a few solutions. The two simplest are:

1. preventDefault on Js
2. change button type or even replace it by eg span

Comment: Thanks Dawid ! i was seeing similar issue even after removing the submit button and using normal but as you said it was the issue with form.